# Magento 2 MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME

Tags: magento, magento2

im new in Magento 2, and i already getting annoyed with it, i made a fresh installation, and in the browser setup all looks ok, after successfully instalation on frontend and backend im getting a error, i cant login on the administration panel, when i load the admin page is giving me this error:

```
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I checked online and many of the comments stated that was missing htacess, in pub/static, but everything is fine, i already clean cache, compile, deploy, etc..
I did it all, but cant understand why still i get the error...

[image]

Frontend Error:
[image]

Note: The strange thing im checking in the console error of the frontend is the error line

```
http://mageuniversity.local/Magento_Theme/js/responsive.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I dont understand how the hell is looking in the root path the "Magento_Theme/js.." have no idea.

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I am also got fed up with this. I have already spent my four day on this. still facing this issue.

Comment: I had this issue just now, but it was due to indicating the the wrong module in the layout/default.xml where I was referencing this, fixed that and this was fixed

Comment: I was facing this issue on an Adobe Commerce Cloud project. Following below steps helped me to resolve the issue `Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75515553/9185662

Answer (score 5):

Static files has not been deploy , try

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f de_DE // or your language code
```

Also keep  dev mode on  it will show errors

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

If still you have same issues run the following commands

```
rm -rf var  generated/* pub/static/*  

chmod 777 -R var generated pub
```

and then again

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Tried this. still facing issue.

Comment: Run these commands
rm -rf var  generated pub/static  
mkdir var generated pub/static
chmod 777 -R var generated pub

Comment: It's not working fine and stopped my website with 500

Answer (score 1):

Try the two magento mode production / developer

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set {mode} [developer|production]`

Check also the owner of all your folders, I think your magento can't create static files.

Comment: tried both developer and production mode. still facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may be missing an important .htaccess file located in pub/static, make sure it is there. If not copy the one from GitHub Magento repo - https://github.com/magento/magento2

If you're not missing the file then it must be an issue with mod rewrite, make sure you've installed it and it is configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<-- Changes in app\code\Magento\Developer\etc\di.xml -->

 Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink  

    -- to --

 Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

First please delete 'static' folder from 'pub/static' in magento 2 before delete this folder please copy .htaccess file from this folder in other folder in your pc. After that using cmd/shell run these commands

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

and

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

and

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

after runing these commands .Paste old .htaccess file into new static folder. Thats it.

Your project working now enjoy!

Comment: If you could add some clarity to this it would be more beneficial.

Comment: Thanks for comment for more clarity in this.

Answer (score 1):

This error could appear when you add Js file in a wrong way. For example when you add "***.js***" to the end of the file.

FOR EXAMPLE:

WRONG

```
/*in a template*/
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/script.js": {
                "variable": "something"
            }
        }
    }
</script>

//OR
/*in a require-config.js file */

var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Vendor_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart/mixin.js': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

RIGHT

```
/*in a template*/    
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/script": {
                "variable": "something"
            }
        }
    }
</script>

//OR
/*in a require-config.js file */

var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Vendor_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/catalog-add-to-cart/mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento version  2.4.5-p1.
I faced the same issue.
In my case the javascript model path was wrong.

```
define([
    'ko',
    'Vendor_Module/js/model/payment/google_pay'
], function (ko) {
    'use strict';

    return ko.observableArray([]);
});
```

I given incorrect path `Vendor_Module/js/model/google_pay` correct path was

```
Vendor_Module/js/model/payment/google_pay
```

So please check the javascript file path.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with 2 different approach. I am explaining fixes;

1- If you are using cloudflare create rule

```
          Rules-Transform Rules -Modify response header - Create Rule
    If  custom filter expression 
URI ends with js
    than
add Content-Type = text/javascript
```

2- php.ini -- You can change default_mimetype

; PHP's built-in default media type is set to text/html.

; https://php.net/default-mimetype

default_mimetype = "text/html"