# Magento 2 backend MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME

Tags: apache, magento2

I have a fresh installation with Magento (Apache on os x). Frontend works, but backend is broken: console gives `Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I have all .htacces files, I have a virtual host etc and tried re-deployed, clear cache methods etc. Nothing works.

Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on an Adobe Commerce Cloud project.
Following below steps helped me to resolve the issue `Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

**Steps**

1. Ensure to dump `app/etc/config.php` from integration or staging environment where you updated your required admin configurations.
2. Then, using ece-tools package command: `php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools config:dump`.
3. Using `scp` CLI command download the remote `app/etc/config.php` file in your local machine.
4. Then, add this file to git, apply git commit and perform a git push.
5. Finally, deploy the latest change to integration -> staging -> production environment.